# memory allocate string for fgets with null terminating char

Tags: c, string, null, fgets

I'm really sorry if this question seems "easy" but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.
I tried to use fgets() to read a line from a file.
To make sure no space was wasted, first of all I found the line's length:

```
do
    {
        c= getc(file);
        words++;
    }while (c!=EOF && c!='\n');
```

then I allocated memory for exacly the number of words:

```
char* line = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(words));
```

and then, I use fgets() to read the line to the line buffer.
But the problem is, this is working.
But I always thought you should allocate memory for the null terminating char too.
So what happened here?

Comment: As a side note: casting the return value of `malloc()` is harmful, and `sizeof(char)` is always 1. So the last line correctly is: `char *line = malloc(words + 1);`

Comment: As an additional note, `words` as a name for a variable counting bytes is a little distracting.

Comment: And for your WHY: Many systems allocate more than you request. The system just guarantees that it doesn't allocate less than the required size, not that it doesn't allocate more (strictly speaking, with overcommitting systems, actually nothing is guaranteed).

Comment: yea that's right, I did it for some reason and didn't change it (i'm talking about the variable name)

Comment: Note that the calls to `getc()` read one line; the subsequent call to `fgets()` reads the next line — unless there's code you've not shown us that records and resets the read position on the input stream (and not all file types are seekable — pipes and terminals to name but two are not).  I suggest using POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) since it can allocate space as necessary automatically.

Comment: Aside from the issue of the count, you can't do things this way, as Jonathan points out. See gcc's `getline` function (source available online) for the right way to do it.

Comment: why isn't it right? i just call rewind()

Comment: BTW: With `c= getc(file); ...while (c!=EOF && c!='\n');`, be sure to use `int c` and not `char c`.  `getc()` returns 1 of 256 different characters _and_ `EOF`.  That's 257 different responses.

Comment: Did you read "not all file types are seekable — pipes and terminals to name but two are not"? And rewind takes you to the beginning of the file ... are you only interested in reading the first line and no other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **do need to allocate space for the null terminator**. The fact that this is working doesn't mean it always will (at least in C).

Plus, `fgets` also returns the `\n` character. So you will need two extra characters. One for `\n` and one for `\0`.

I would recommend this approach though:

```
char buffer [1024];
if ( fgets (buffer, 1024, f) != NULL ) {
   // so something with buffer
}
```

Comment: I don't need extra two, you can see that I've counted the \n

Comment: But i'm still interested about WHY it is working. and I don't want to waste space with this approach.

Comment: You can go much smaller than 1024 if you're worried about space.  But unless you're doing work on a very restricted environment the space/time tradeoff should probably go to time here.

Comment: @user3050072 it's not working. It *pretends* to be working. It's undefined behavior. "undefined" means "undefined" and not "defined to crash". Also, why so serious about space? 1024 bytes won't hurt... did you measure that this specific amount of space causes a performance bottleneck? If not, then don't worry about it.

Comment: not really, but i'm more concerned about buffer overflow

Comment: @user3050072 or rather a stack overflow (it seems to me)? Just don't.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant No, the OP is concerned with buffer overflow ... the undefined behavior from writing beyond the bounds of the allocated array. Stack overflow isn't a concern except with unbounded recursion or allocating large arrays on the stack. C's dirty little secret is that there are virtually **no** strictly conforming C programs because there is no minimum guaranteed stack size. The standard doesn't even provide a minimum guaranteed call depth (despite various other guaranteed minimums in section 5.2.4.1).

Comment: `fgets (buffer, 1024, f)` is OK, but suggest `fgets (buffer, sizeof buffer, f)` as  even better.  +1 for the right approach.

Comment: @JimBalter I know that it's not a concern, that's why I suggested "just don't". What led me to believe OP is confusing buffer overflow with stack overflow is that he "didn't want to waste space".

Comment: So i should just limit the size for a size that "makes sense"? How can it be safe?

Comment: and by the way I get why you confused but I meant buffer overflow ;)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant The question and most of the OP's comments are about buffer overflow, then the OP said he/she is "not really" so serious about space, but is "more concerned about buffer overflow". So the confusion is not the OP's ...

Comment: @JimBalter in which case [s]he didn't answer my question, for what I can't be blamed...

Comment: guys can you answer my question: So i should just limit the size for a size that "makes sense"? How can it be safe?

Comment: @user3050072: You start with some reasonable size and resize (`realloc`) if your buffer happens to be too small. See e.g. [POSIX `getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html#). If you're on a non-POSIX system, you can write something similar yourself.

Comment: Addressing your original question: You already count one too much (so you don't need to add 1 for the 0-terminator) in the case your input doesn't end in `'\n'` (you also count `EOF`). `fgets` is always safe if you pass it the right buffer size, it doesn't write more than one less than the size passed plus the 0-terminator. So if the input ends with a newline, it's just not read by `fgets` (assuming you pass `words` as the size argument to `fgets`).

Answer (score 1):

Its working by pure luck.  Writing past the end of allocated memory is undefined behavior.  It isn't an instant crash.  It may crash instantly, or later on down the line, or it may work just fine.  It all depends on how big the overwrite is and what the memory immediately after is used for.  It will frequently be padding or currently unused space, and thus just work.  You can't count on that though.  The correct answer is to malloc 2 more characters than needed (1 for the terminator and 1 for the \n that fgets will copy).

Comment: For malloced memory, it will either be padding or the beginning of the next malloc block, resulting in a later crash in malloc. Some debugging versions of malloc (such as the one used in Visual Studio for debug builds) put recognizable guard bytes before and after allocated memory and checks whether they have been overwritten so as to provide more informative diagnostics.